# Pre-creating chart objects based on templates

Tags: highcharts

Is it possible to wrap a highcharts chart in a function that uses templates to define the chart, pass the chart data in during the render process then render it to a div. Essentially, I need to pre-build a chart object and render it to a div at a specific time.

Comment: Let me know if you mean how to prepaare a template (json) with chart option, which can be used in different charts with own data (per chart) ?

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what I'm trying to do here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prepare a global json and use merge() function or push objects directly to template.

```
    var template = {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        data:[]
    }]
  };

    template.title.text = 'Pie chart 1';
  template.series[0].data = [['aaa1',3],['bbb1',4],['ccc1',5]];
  $('#container1').highcharts(template);

  template.title.text = 'Pie chart 2';
  template.series[0].data = [['aaa2',3],['bbb2',4],['ccc2',5]];
  $('#container2').highcharts(template);
```

Simple demo: http://jsfiddle.net/80fsL5x5/

```
    var template = {
    chart: {
      type: 'pie'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    plotOptions: {
      pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %',
          style: {
            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.contrastTextColor) || 'black'
          }
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
        data:[]
    }]
  };

    var options1 = {
    title:{
        text: 'Pie chart 1'
    },
    series:[{
        data: [['aaa1',3],['bbb1',4],['ccc1',5]]
    }]
  };

  $('#container1').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(template,options1));

  var options2 = {
    title:{
        text: 'Pie chart 2'
    },
    series:[{
        data: [['aaa2',3],['bbb2',4],['ccc2',5]]
    }]
  };
  $('#container2').highcharts(Highcharts.merge(template,options2));
```

Demo with merge: http://jsfiddle.net/w46rm4vj/